# SignalR - Mensagem Offline

Tags: signalr

Estou desenvolvendo um chat utilizando signalR 2.2.0 e me deparei com o seguinte problema, desejo enviar uma mensagem a um usuario da minha lista de contato que não esta online no momento, pra quando ele entrar ele receba a mensagem, alguem que ja tenha feito essa parte, pode está me explicando como fez? ou tem algum link ou tutorial que aborda esse assunto?

Comment: Ola a todos, tentando esclarecer mais a minha pergunta, meu chat esta  funcionando legal, porem estou conseguindo enviar mensagem apenas para usuários online, gostaria de enviar mensagem para usuários offline de modo que a mensagem fique armazenada e seja entregue quando o destinatário se conectar ao chat ... utilizando signalR, não encontrei nada sobre o assunto, caso saibam algum tutorial para me indicarem ou até mesmo se tiverem feito e poder disponibilizar agradeço!